# An Issue with the video aesthetic

Tags: joomla1.5

I have been trying to get this video in the site embedded. But the problem is that once I click on the video twice, the link gets redirected to the corresponding You Tube page. Also is it possible to get away with the You Tube logos or the message that appears along with the video.

```
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/9UNdMgmW8EY&hl=en_US&fs=1&amp" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="500" height="300"></embed>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [AllVideos Reloaded](http://allvideos.fritz-elfert.de/) component.  It handles YouTube and other popular video sites files very well.  There are parameters you can set which will disable the related videos.. something like "&rel=0"